# Dynamic allocation of vectors in a class

Tags: c++, class, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation

If I have a class that contains a vector of another class and I'm expecting it to be very long:

```
class NucleotideSequence{
private:
    std::string Name;
    std::vector<Nucleotide> Sequence;
public:
    NucleotideSequence();
    NucleotideSequence(std::string name, std::vector<Nucleotide> seq);
    std::string getName();
    Nucleotide* getBase(int pos1);
    int getLength();
    void print();
};
```

In this case the vector Sequence, do I need to dynamically allocate it by making Sequence *Sequence and making a new vector during the constructor? I want to make sure I use the right resource (stack vs heap) for large vectors (over hundreds of thousands of elements). Which is the right thing to do? I heard vectors wrap the dynamic array allocation.

EDIT:

I've provided the updated code below to show I've used reference passing for the constructor. I hope to use a move constructor too so I can make these objects in a function and then move them outside.

Also given is the updated getPos method which throws the error if the position does not exist in the sequence.

```
class NucleotideSequence{
private:
    std::string Name;
    std::vector<Nucleotide> Sequence;
public:
    NucleotideSequence();
    NucleotideSequence(const std::string &name, const std::vector<Nucleotide> &seq); // Note that a pointer is not needed since the std::vector class allocated memory on the heap for us and is a wrapper for that whole RAII process.
    std::string getName();
    Nucleotide getBase(int pos);
    int getLength();
    void print();
};

NucleotideSequence::NucleotideSequence(const std::string &name, const std::vector<Nucleotide> &seq)
{
    Name = name;
    Sequence = seq;
}

// Get a specific base
Nucleotide NucleotideSequence::getBase(int pos)
{
    for(std::vector<Nucleotide>::iterator i = Sequence.begin(); i != Sequence.end(); i++)
    {
        if(pos == i->getPos())
        {
            return *i; // Return the correct nucleotide object.
        }
    }
    throw BoundsError(); // If the desired position is not found, throw the error.
}
```

Thanks,
Ben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is better to keep your variable member `Sequence` as a `std::vector` (and not a `pointer` to `std::vector`). As you mentioned "*vectors wrap the dynamic array allocation*": `std::vector` manages for you the memory (heap allocation / deallocation / reallocation) in a `RAII` fashion:
When you write: `std::vector<Nucleotide> Sequence`, `Sequence` stores the objects `Nucleotide` on the `heap` (not on the `stack`)

One suggestion: in your constructor, you are passing the `std::vector` by value (as well as the `std::string`). Passing by value is expensive if your `std::vector` has a large size. You need to consider if passing by reference can be applied in your case.

Answer (score 1):

All `vector`s are on the heap and allocated dynamically.  The way you have it declared is fine, but you probably should initialize it in your constructor anyway.

`NucleotideSequence`... I *bet* it's a big array.

Comment: Aside not related to your question: `Nucleotide` is a tiny data type (as long as you're not passing around the quantum states of the electrons in the aromatic rings) so you may want to return it by value from `getBase`.  That will avoid issues where the `vector` gets reallocated to accommodate a bigger sequence and all pointers to the old one are invalidated.

Comment: When I return a pointer with the getPos() function if the position does not exist, I return a nullptr, if I have to return a Nucleotide I'm unsure how to handle the situation where the user enters a position that does not exist.I suppose in this case if I return the value I can send a message to stderr and return an empty nucleotide object or one hat encodes 'N'.

Comment: @Ward9250 you've made the length available to the client code, so it's not wrong to throw an exception for attempting to access an out-of-bounds base.  You'll get a better error message that way.  Further aside: I wish you were using a language that had a general purpose `Object.clone`.  That would make for a good joke.

Comment: You are right it may well be a big array - I'm building an analyser for a research project on large sequences like genomic sequences. It removes as much unnecessary noninformative-information as possible from sequences but I am wondering if I'll need to move from the classes I've written above - Nucleotide contains the base and the position (char and int), and NucleotideSequence is a vector of Nucleotides and a string with the sequence name. I've looked at encoding nucleotides as two bits but it feels quite complex and is easily a whole other question by itself.

Comment: @Ward9250 It will be very complex to use 2 bits; there is the added bonus of being able to use bit operations to rapidly get the complimentary bases, but that isn't a lot of payoff relative to the gymnastics you'll have to do to get C++ to opaquely use a 2 bit type.  That goes double if your program needs to be extended to handle RNA, methylation, etc. etc.  Might be good for storage on disk, though.

Comment: I have considered a way to cut the initial sequence read in by half reading in two bases at a time, and assigning a value to them, e.g. AA is 'a', AT is 'b' and so on. Having my program work out where the informative sites are, extract them and convert them back to a more basic format like my Nucleotide class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  wraps the whole dynamically allocated array thing.
You dont need to dynamically allocate one, and its usually wrong to do so. Just declare them as straight data members like you have.

But, vectors use value semantics, and thus there is a potential down side of doing this, in that the resulting class will be very expensive to copy/assign (much the way large vectors are expensive to copy/assign).

This is usually fine, it just makes it a large things, and large things are just usually passed by reference when passing them around, so make sure you pass your sequence around by reference, not pass it around by value. (And of course you have provided no copy-ctr/assignment operator, so you were likely going to do this anyway)

Comment: Hi, I do intend to add a move constructor and a copy constructor to the class, especially a move constructor after seeing a talk by Bjarne about C++ style and moving large or complex variables outside of a function rather than returning by value. Why would I need to overload the assignment operator? (since learning C++ texts I've read mostly cover constructors and destuctors and so these other things are new to me). I'm aware of operator overloading with classes but haven't used it yet.